# forceUpdate in nested components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I am having following component in which a list of products will be displayed. the CounterComponent is added in two places, one in ProductCatalog and the other one in ProductCard which can be shown i a modal. I display the number of ordered product in counter. 
I want to synchronize these two counters as one is updated. using forceUpdate on each of the counter state change doesn't do the trick.

```
export default class ProductCatalog extends Component {

showProductCard(product){
  var scope = this;
  $('.ui.modal.' + product.code)
  .modal({
    onHide: function(){
      scope.forceUpdate();
    }
  }).modal('show');
}

render() {
    var scope = this;

    return (
        <div className="ui grid" id="productCatalog">
            {
                this.props.products.map(function(raw) {

                    return (
                          <div className="product" onClick={scope.showProductCard.bind(scope, product)}></div>
                          <div className="extra content">
                            <CounterComponent 
                                count={scope.props.getProductCount(product)}
                                product={product}
                                onCountChanged={scope.props.onCountChanged}>
                            </CounterComponent>

                          <ProductCard
                            count={scope.props.getProductCount(product)}
                            product={product}
                            onCountChanged={scope.props.onCountChanged}>
                          </ProductCard>

                          </div>
                        );
                })
            }

        </div>
        );
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code of your CounterComponent? Normally you shouldn't need to use ```forceUpdate``` as your components should simply re-render when you pass new values for props. IMO it's also a bit strange to pass onCountChanged to the CounterComponent, because you know when the counter value changes directly in the parent, so to me it looks like the CounterComponent doesn't need to know what to do when it changes, as the parent can deal with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forceupdate is most likely not needed in this case. Any react component only should need a rerender when state changes or when props change.
And react handles this automatically.

In your case:

- Either pass your product count as a prop to the `<ProductCart>`
- Or save the count in state.

In your case: it seems like the parent already knows the product count, since you are calling a function to retrieve it.

Better to pass the product count as props, instead of calling a method to retrieve the count.